# Сохранение в куки несколько массивов

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой JS код:

```
var arr = [
    [
       ['Name', 'Years'],
       ['Yuri', '16']
    ],
    [
       ['Login', 'Password'],
       ['good1', '111']
    ]
]
```

Когда я сохраняю `arr` в куки, то оно сохраняет всё, как один массив (все соединяет в один большой)
Как мне сделать, что бы оно сохраняло так же, что бы массив, был в массиве после загрузки куков

Comment: а **как** вы сохраняете `arr` в куки?

Comment: По такому принципу `localStorage.setItem('ключ', 'значение')`

Comment: так как в `localStorage` хранятся только строки, при такой записи `localStorage.setItem('ключ', arr)` _arr_ приводилось к строке и вы получали значение аналогичное при вызове _arr.toString()_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте сериализацию. Сохранение в виде строки:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

При получении из куки строкового представления, разворачиваете обратно в массив:

```
var arr=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(string));
```